# Linear transformation between two vector spaces with different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given two vector spaces, with the following bases:

$\alpha = \left \{ (1,2,5), (3,2,0), (1,1,1) \right \}$

$\beta = \left \{ (1,7), (1,2) \right \}$

Suppose we have a linear application $f$ that is defined as follows:

$f : \mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$

$f(1,2,5) = (3,5)$

$f(3,2,0) = (5,1)$

$f(1,1,1) = (2,1)$

So, I need to calculate the matrix associated with the linear application. I have done the following:

$M(f) = ( f(1,2,5) |  f(3,2,0) |  f(1,1,1) )$

$M(f) = \begin{pmatrix}
3 &  5& 2\\ 
5 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

The problem is that I don't know if the images of the vectors of the base $\alpha$ I have to express them this way or according to the base $\beta$ they give me. Well, in that case, the associated matrix would be different.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write $f(1,2,5)$ as a linear combination $\alpha(1,7)+\beta(1,2)$ of $(1,7)$ and $(1,2)$. You can get these coefficients solving a system of linear equations. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will form the first column of your matrix. Then, do the same thing with $f(3,2,0)$ and of $f(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Can I resolve this by myself? And then tell me if it is correct or not.

Comment: Sure. Solve it yourself, and I will check it.

Comment: Imagine that I know that $f(3,3,3)=(9,3)$ , $f(1,0,4)=(1,4)$ and $f(3,0,5)=(3,5)$. How do I calculate the matrix of f with respect to the bases α and β?

Comment: That is another question. Please post it as such.

Comment: Okey, I will do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to express the output in terms of $\beta$ for the matrix. For example, $(3,5)=-\frac 1 5 (1,7) + \frac{16} 5 (1,2)$ and so the first column of the matrix should be $\begin{pmatrix}-\frac 1 5\\\frac{16}5\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Imagine that I know that $f(3,3,3)=(9,3)$, $f(1,0,4)=(1,4)$ and $f(3,0,5)=(3,5)$. How do I calculate the matrix of f with respect to the bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: You would need to solve the equations $(9,3)=a_1(1,7)+a_2(1,2)$, $(1,4)=b_1(1,7)+b_2(1,2)$, and  $(3,5)=c_1(1,7)+c_2(1,2)$. The matrix would then be $\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 & b_3 \\ a_2 & b_2 & b_3 \end{pmatrix}$